# Search by sku not working for particular product in solarium

Tags: magento-1.9, search, third-party-module, solr

I have solarium extension names JeroenVermeulen_Solarium.
I am facing product with search by sku. For particular sku i am not getting that product. I have sku ANK15120-00SPC. If i search for 15120 it should give me ANK15120-00SPC this sku product.
I am using solr version 3.6.2.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue with below setting

go to `System->configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search->` and set `Search Type` to `Like` or `Fulltext or Like`

refresh the cache and check again.

Comment: I set to fulltext but still it doesn't work.

Comment: set to `like` search because your requirement is for `like` search

Comment: Its not working. I think it's not related to configuration.